# What is the Bikercoin currency?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

[Bikercoin](http://bikercoin.org/) is a new currency (released on June 7th 2016) based on the CryptoNote protocol.

What are the major differences between Bikercoin and Monero? What source code are they forking from?

Comment: to the people downvoting - please leave a comment why so the question can be adjusted accordingly. I don't see any reason for the question being off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a Monero stack exchange I'm not going to go too deep into what differentiates Bikercoin from Monero. However, a quick examination of their [listed GitHub repository](https://github.com/scriptexpert/bikercoin) indicates that it is indeed a fork from CryptoNote.

The commit history indicates a substantial number of adjustments (including [change donation](https://github.com/scriptexpert/bikercoin/commit/00915e6d3428667951f56d545f67ef6e795172b5)) and there are currently no pull requests in place which indicate a largely solo or small team effort.

Given the overall level of activity and network effect on the back end it seems prudent to dismiss this as a simple alt-coin that doesn't add much value to the Monero ecosystem.